# installing ubuntu onto a netbook and a pc

Tags: acer

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto an acer aspire one happy using a bootable usb stick and it works. So I tried to install using the same medium onto my Pc and acer aspire M1800 but I get a message "unable to locate a medium with a live file system" ? and a load of other information what gives ? both computers use windows 7 the netbook had a magor cock up and ubuntu saved the day( sort of) this also happens when I use a cd I cannot figure out what is going on

Comment: Did you uninstall windows 7 or is it still the primary OS on the system. Just yesterday I did something similar and found out this UEFI was causing issues with booting from other drives. I wiped Windows from my system though, so thats why I ask. This UEFI is a pain.

Comment: Is your PC 32 bit and notebook 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

press F12 or what ever it prompts to change boot sequence at ACER POST screen.
BTW you may have to press F2 at ACER screen, and Enable the F12 BOOT MENU.

after getting into the boot menu choices:
choose the option that shows your bootable usb stick.

enjoy.